# RefactoringTool: ParseError: bad input: type=22, value='='

Tags: python, python-2to3

I'm refactoring some python2 code and changing it to python3 using 2to3 module. I've received following parse error:

```
RefactoringTool: There was 1 error:
RefactoringTool: Can't parse ./helpers/repo.py: ParseError: bad input: type=22, value='=', context=(' ', (45, 25))
```

Here is a code that yields the error:

```
    except ImportError as error_msg:  # pragma: no cover                           
        print(' ',  file = sys.stderr) # this is a line that yields error                                          
        print("Could not locate modifyrepo.py", file=sys.stderr)                
        print("That is odd... should be with createrepo", file=sys.stderr)      
        raise ImportError(error_msg)
```

I have no clue what could be wrong. Can you please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2to3 ParseError in python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523611/2to3-parseerror-in-python-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the code that you're trying to convert is not valid Python 2 code.

When running your code using Python 2, you'll get the following error:

```
  File "repo.py", line 5
    print(' ',  file = sys.stderr) # this is a line that yields error
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems like this code already is Python 3 code. Using Python 3 your code does not yield a SyntaxError.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! In the meantime I found this: https://bugs.python.org/issue35260, but still couldn't grasp what's wrong.

Comment: @cmd, the first response on that bug report actually says the same: "2to3 expects a valid Python 2 file as input, and the file a.py isn't a valid Python 2 file: the `print` line is a SyntaxError in the absence of a `from __future__ import print_function`. So yes, this *is* being treated like Python 2 code, but that's what 2to3 is designed to do."

Answer (score 2):

If you have already converted your `print` statements to functions (as you have done) you can use the `-p` parameter when invoking `2to3`

> -p, --print-function  Modify the grammar so that print() is a
> function

E.g.

```
2to3 -p yourfile.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue.
My print statements were already converted to functions.

The issue was that the import of the print function was done as

```
from __future__ import (
    unicode_literals,
    print_function,
)
```

To fix it, I had to put the import on a separate, dedicated line line

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I found that absolute import addressing sorted this for me.  Syntax was all fine, but relative import with the following gave an error.

Failed:

`from . import classes.utility as util`

Works:

`from classes import utility as util`

This may just be my lack of understanding of imports in Python3 though.